# Spring boot API timeout and HTTP timeout in weblogic

Tags: rest, api, spring-boot, weblogic

I am in the process of setting up a spring rest api using spring boot.
This will be deployed on weblogic server.
this api will perform a db operation which can potentially take anywhere between a few seconds to an hour.
Am planning to use spring's 'DeferredResult' and 'ForkJoinPool' to trigger the database operation asynchronously.

I would like to perform a timeout and inform the end user if I dont get a response from the db operation after lets say 30 seconds.

So I will be setting this configuration for my rest api to timeout after 30 seconds.

My question : are there any weblogic http timeouts that could occur ?
If yes then my api configured timeout would need to be less than the server timeout 
or
I would need to increase the server timeout such that it is greater than the API timeout .

Any thoughts on the approach would be great .

Comment: I think the HTTP timeout is only settable at the client side, not in WebLogic. A jdbc timeout between your application and your database could be more usefull.